# Telling ArrayList to .add() Itself in Java

Tags: java

I came across this code. I was wondering if this is possible. As you can see, aList is an ArrayList which .adds() itself.

```
ArrayList<Object> aList;
aList = new ArrayList<Object>();
aList.add("cat"); 
aList.add(aList);
aList.add(12);
int size = 0;
Iterator<Object> it = aList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
 it.next();
 size++;
}
System.out.print(size);
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, an `ArrayList` is an object like any other object, so you can add it to itself. This is probably not something that's very useful in practice, however.

Comment: Try instead:    aList.addAll(aList);

Comment: @kylexy1357 which is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Stultuske is the question itself revelant?

Comment: @kylexy1357 yes. it means "can the list itself" be added to the list, not "can the elements of the list be added to the list again"

Comment: @Jesper: Yes, I know. There was a multiple-choice portion on a UIL pdf, and one of the answer choices was: D. Code will not compile, or something of the sort. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Did you know there are online IDEs that you can use to quickly check code? For example: https://ideone.com/

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks! I will start using that. Very convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  There are no restrictions on the elements you can add to a `ArrayList<Object>`.

And you can iterate the list, and do various other things with it.

But don't call `toString()` on it because you *might* get a `StackOverflowError`.

---

**UPDATE** - For (at least) Oracle / OpenJDK Java 6 and onwards, the `toString()` method inherited from `AbstractCollection` will detect this "self reference" cycle and show it as `(this collection)` rather than going into an infinite recursive loop.

However:

1. This is an implementation detail.  It is not part of the specification.
2. I don't know if this applies for all Java versions; i.e. prior to Java 6, and Android versions.
3. This doesn't apply for 3rd-party `List` classes that don't extend `AbstractCollection`.  (For them, you would need to check the implementation code to understand what would happen.)
4. It doesn't apply if the self-reference cycle has more than one "hop"; e.g. list A contains list B, and list B contains list A.  In such cases you *would* get infinite recursion and a `StackOverflowError`.

So caution is advised.